# Can't stop promise chain javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, streaming, chaining

I have a stream of text that I send to a function to turn into speech. I send the text sentence by sentence for better latency. The issue im running into is handling interruptions. Right now, I send each sentence to a function containing a promise. So I end up with a chain of awaits that pile on fairly quickly, so when I try to interrupt the function, althought it properly breaks out, the await chain continues to run. Here is a snippet of the code (send_voice returns a promise)

```
const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: conversation_history,
      stream: true,
    });

    let sentence = ""; 

    for await (const chunk of stream) {
      
      const content = chunk.choices[0]?.delta?.content || "";
      sentence += content; 

      if (interruptionState.value){
        console.log("breaking");
        break; //break correctly called but send_voice chain continues
      }
      
      if (sentence.endsWith('.') || sentence.endsWith('!') || sentence.endsWith('?')) {
        
        console.log("FINAL: ", sentence);
        
        conversation_history.push({ "role": "system", "content": sentence });
        
        await send_voice(sentence, ws, elleven_key, voice_id,interruptionState); 
        sentence = ""; 
      }
    }
```

I know that I can't stop the await chain, but is there any way around this? I essentially need to call send_voice sequentially and be able to stop it quickly on interruption. I've been stuck on this for a while so any help would be much appreciated!

I've been stuck on this for a while so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```js
const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: conversation_history,
  stream: true,
});
const improveStream = stream.map(item => {
  return new Promise(async res => {
    item.then(async chunk => {
      await checkInterruptionState()
      res(chunk)
    })
  })
})

function checkInterruptionState() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    if (interruptionState.value) {
      console.log("breaking");
      //break correctly called but send_voice chain continues
      const Interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!interruptionState.value) {
           clearInterval(Interval )
          res()
        }
      }, 200)

    } else {
      res()
    }
  })
}
let sentence = "";

for await (const chunk of improveStream ) {

  const content = chunk.choices[0] ? .delta ? .content || "";
  sentence += content;
  if (sentence.endsWith('.') || sentence.endsWith('!') || sentence.endsWith('?')) {

    console.log("FINAL: ", sentence);

    conversation_history.push({
      "role": "system",
      "content": sentence
    });

    await send_voice(sentence, ws, elleven_key, voice_id, interruptionState);
    sentence = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Im a little confused by the code here, what is this trying to do?

Comment: using improveStream  instead stream , then the chunk can be break when the interruptionState.value is true